# HTML Tag for the full current URL - IonCube

Tags: php, html, url, ioncube

I am creating a website using IonCube. I can use some PHP coding in the HTML page templates, however, I would like to know how to get the FULL URL plus a link when I click on it. For example, My current URL is:

```
http://example.com/site_search.php?option_1=1&option_2=1
```

and when I click on a link, it directs me to another added option, so the result will be:

```
http://example.com/site_search.php?option_1=1&option_2=1&option_3&option_4=8
```

As you have seen, these are options, and users can select anything.

I appreciate your help
 - Thanks

Comment: After clicking the link, navigate to the same page with some additional options. Is this your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply

Comment: You can get $_GET['option_1'] to get the value of the option_1 and then pass it again for the same page using link.

Comment: Problem is resolved but thanks for your help :)